# Two rows with Add More buttons not adding new rows correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attaching the following screenshot to hopefully help illustrate my issue.

[image]

The screenshot above shows two rows each with its own **Add More** button represented with a plus (+) sign.

The first row has three textboxes, First Name, Last Name and Email.

The second row also has three textboxes, Source, Address and Income.

When you click the plus sign add more rows to the first row, it works fine because the rows are added right after the default row. Where the row is added for the first row is represented with a black arrow.

The second Add More button (+) for the second row is not working correctly.
It is adding the rows but instead of adding the rows to where the red arrow is, it is adding it where the black arrow is as though it was being added to the first row.

I know I am doing something wrong but can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Dynamic Rows</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { //
            var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;  
            var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="f-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="l-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="email' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>' +  
                '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +  
                '</tr>';  
            $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class  
        });
    });  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { //
            var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person2').length + 1;  
            var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person2">' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>' +  
                '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact2 btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +  
                '</tr>';  
            $('#maintable2').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class  
        })

        $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact2", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls 
        });        
    });  
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>Basic Table</h2>  
            <table class="table" id="maintable">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Firstname</th>  
                        <th>Lastname</th>  
                        <th>Email</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="f-name" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="l-name" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control email01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table> 

             <table class="table" id="maintable2">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Source </th>  
                        <th>Address </th>  
                        <th>Income</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person2">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourcename" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourceaddress" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourceincome" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table>   
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm">Submit</button>  
        </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

//Latest code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete1" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });

            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd2", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person2').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person2">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="spousename' + rowCount + '" class="form-control spousename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="spouseaddress' + rowCount + '" class="form-control spouseaddress01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="spouseincome' + rowCount + '" class="form-control spouseincome01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete2" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Add More</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable2').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });

        $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls 
        });

        function getAllEmpData() {
            var data = [];
            $('tr.data-contact-person').each(function () {
                var sname = $(this).find('.sourcename01').val();
                var saddress = $(this).find('.sourceaddress01').val();
                var sincome = $(this).find('.sourceincome01').val();
                var spname = $(this).find('.spousename01').val();
                var spaddress = $(this).find('.spouseaddress01').val();
                var spincome = $(this).find('.spouseincome01').val();
                var alldata = {
                    'mySource': sname,
                    'mySAddress': saddress,
                    'mySIncome': sincome,
                    'mySpouse': spname,
                    'mySPAddress': spaddress,
                    'mySPIncome': spincome
                }
                data.push(alldata);
            });
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
            //console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveData',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                success: function () {
                    alert("Data Added Successfully");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while inserting data");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SaveData(empdata As String) As String
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Employee))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            For Each data As Employee In serializedData
                Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SourceDetails(sourcename, sourceaddress, sourceincome, createDate) VALUES(@sname, @saddress,@sincome,@CreatedDate)")

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", data.mySpouse)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saddress", data.mySAddress)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sincome", data.mySIncome)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: I bet if you either add 2 different onclick classes (.addClass1, .addClass2) rather than 1 or just set up one set of code and put it within a each loop to target the proper fields it'll work properly..

Comment: @Rick, I will appreciate your help with the second option.

Thank you.

Comment: can you put running jsfiddle here would be easy to debug and check

Comment: @MGA, sure. Here is the fiddle.

It works using the first option recommended by Rick but the second option will allow me to add more button controls for more rows later.

Here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rtdtjg2f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace the head part with this.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dynamic Rows</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="f-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="l-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="email' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete1" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });

            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd2", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person2').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person2">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete2" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable2').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

You need to learn some rules about basic html and others, like:

Don't repeat the same id in two or more elements.

You can repeat classes but not ids.

And use just one $(document).ready(function(){}).

Note that I changed the some things about that and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the first option working.. Nice! Here's basically the second option I was referring to..

https://jsfiddle.net/03u8z77y/

You can add some sort of class to better target your dynamic areas as well so you don't accidentally target unwanted tables..

Maybe the below..

```
<tbody>
```

Becomes

```
<tbody class="my-target">
```

UPDATE (per your latest code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $form1 = $('#form1');

    $form1.on("click", ".add-source", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $tbody = $this.closest('tbody'),
            rowCount = $tbody.find('.data-contact-person').length + 1,
            contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][' + rowCount + '][name]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][' + rowCount + '][address]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][' + rowCount + '][income]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary add-source">Add More</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">Remove</button></td>' +
                '</tr>';
        $tbody.append(contactdiv);
    });

    $form1.on("click", ".add-spouse", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $tbody = $this.closest('tbody'),
            rowCount = $tbody.find('.data-contact-person').length + 1,
            contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][' + rowCount + '][name]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][' + rowCount + '][address]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][' + rowCount + '][income]" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary add-spouse">Add More</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">Remove</button></td>' +
                '</tr>';
        $tbody.append(contactdiv);
    });

    $form1.on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });

    $form1.on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveData',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $form1.serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("Data Added Successfully");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

And the form..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div class="container">  
        <h2>Basic Table</h2>  
        <table class="table">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>Firstname</th>  
                    <th>Lastname</th>  
                    <th>Email</th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][0][name]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][0][address]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[source][0][income]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary add-source">Add More</button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </tbody>  
        </table> 

         <table class="table">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>Source </th>  
                    <th>Address </th>  
                    <th>Income</th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][0][name]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][0][address]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="empdata[spouse][0][income]" class="form-control" /></td>  
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary add-spouse">Add More</button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </tbody>  
        </table>   
        <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm">Submit</button>  
    </div>  
</form>
```

Now I didn't test this but let me know how it works out..

Comment: your solution is so cool but I don't understand it.

As it stands with your solution, I can even add more Add More buttons and they work but I can't figure out what you changed.

Thank you and thanks to all who responded.

Comment: basically I'm just applying your code to each "tbody" on the page. you were calling them individually.

Comment: So, how are we going to be able to tell them when a row count has been incremented using  `+ rowCount + `. It seems to me that on f-name, l-name, email row has the ability to be incremented.

Comment: You can update this "var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;" to this "var rowCount = $this.find('.data-contact-person').length + 1;". Be sure class "data-contact-person" exists in both groups. You'll then have correct counts for each group. If you plan on posting this info I'd update the input names to build an array. Something like (name="contact[' + rowCount + '][f_name]") and (name="source[' + rowCount + '][f_name]"). And I just realized you have different field names for each group. May have to revert back to option 1 or create a template for each group but that gets crazy..

Comment: when you say posting this info, do you mean submit to the database?

If that's what you mean, then yes, that's the end goal which is why I like your solution. The less code the better.

Comment: Yes post to the server/database.. And yes I agree, less code the better, but I just don't think it's worth all the effort in getting it to work on what you have there. Might just be much quicker and easier solution to just go with option 1 and call it good. I mean you're getting into templates and cloning and indexing and stuff.. Let me know what you decide.. I'll assist if you need it.

Comment: Ok, I will go with option one. However, if  I am going with option one, I think andrewrosvel 's solution is a better solution. It is easier to understand and I can add or remove more Add More/Remove buttons.

Comment: Should work.. same thing my option 1 was.. actually looks like all 3 of us suggested that option.

Comment: I am having problems posting data to the database.

Do you mind if I show the code and see if you can help?

Comment: sure I'll take a peek

Comment: Thanks. I am usually pretty ok with asp.net and inserting records into the database.

However, I am using ajax call and json object as you can see and if you know why I am having issues and can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Dynamic Rows</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { //
            var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;  
            var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="f-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="l-name' + rowCount + '" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="email' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>' +  
                '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +  
                '</tr>';  
            $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class  
        });
    });  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $(document).on("click", ".classAdd2", function () { //
            var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person2').length + 1;  
            var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person2">' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><input type="text" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +  
                '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd2">+</button>' +  
                '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact2 btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>' +  
                '</tr>';  
            $('#maintable2').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class  
        })

        $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact2", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls 
        });        
    });  
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>Basic Table</h2>  
            <table class="table" id="maintable">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Firstname</th>  
                        <th>Lastname</th>  
                        <th>Email</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="f-name" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="l-name" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control email01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">+</button>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table> 

             <table class="table" id="maintable2">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Source </th>  
                        <th>Address </th>  
                        <th>Income</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person2">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourcename" class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourceaddress" class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" name="sourceincome" class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd2">+</button>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table>   
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm">Submit</button>  
        </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Its because you have used same class ".classAdd" on both on click jquery code. Change another class to ".classAdd2". And remove duplicate line $(document).ready(function () { . You can use console in web inspector to see javascript erros.